# How can I implement the same list as the proto in c #?

Tags: c#, .net, proto

In the proto file I have a reply message called *GetActiveInvoicesReply*, which represents a list of type *GetActiveInvoices*, with its 3 elements.
In C # how do you invoke this list, in the *Task.FromResult ()* method?

**invoice-repository.proto**

```
  syntax = "proto3";
    
    import public "Protos/Invoice/invoice-common.proto";
    import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
    
    option csharp_namespace = "InvoiceService.Grpc.Invoice";
    
    package Invoice.Repository;
    
    service InvoiceRepository {
        rpc GetActiveInvoices (GetActiveInvoicesRequest) returns (GetActiveInvoicesReply);
    }
      
    message GetActiveInvoicesRequest {
        Invoice.Common.PartitaIva partitaIva = 1;
    }
    
    message GetActiveInvoices {
        string statoFattura = 1;
        google.protobuf.Timestamp data = 2;
        string message = 3;
    }
    
    message GetActiveInvoicesReply {
        repeated GetActiveInvoices getActiveInvoices = 1;
    }
```

**InvoiceRepositoryService.cs**

```
public override Task<GetActiveInvoicesReply> GetActiveInvoices(GetActiveInvoicesRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {

            var parameters = mapPartitaIva(request);
            var getActiveInvoices = new List<GetActiveInvoices>();
            return Task.FromResult(new GetActiveInvoicesReply
            {
                   //what I write here?
            });

        }

        private PartitaIva mapPartitaIva(GetActiveInvoicesRequest request)
        {
            return new PartitaIva
            {
                paese = request.PartitaIva.Paese,
                codice = request.PartitaIva.Codice
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would code for whatever specific logic is required in your system to pull the active invoices.  It could be a database call, or it could be another API call to a different service of some sort.  We don't know how your back-end logic is structured.

Comment: Is there a good reason your method needs to return a Task? It's not asynchronous, so it's better to not unnecessarily wrap your return type in unneeded types.

Comment: @AndrewH: `Task<T>` doesn't require the use of the `async` keyword to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what your implementation of GetActiveInvoicesReply looks like so I can only assume it follows the identifiers defined in your proto file:

```
...

var getActiveInvoices = new List<GetActiveInvoices>();
return Task.FromResult(new GetActiveInvoicesReply
{
    getActiveInvoices = getActiveInvoices
});

...
```